# How to push the Selection of a UIPicker to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

how can I push the User Selection of a UIPicker to Firebase Database? So for example he hit on "male" than it will be stored in the Firebase Database...

My code for the UI Picker

```
class AddExtraData: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[row]
    }
    

    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    
    
    let data = ["male", "female", "else"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        
    }
```

EDIT:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjC4V.png)

Here is my database.

Now I want to get to write the data which is stored in seclectedYearPicker to the database.

```
  var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    let selectedYearPicker = data[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    print(selectedYearPicker)
    
    
    
                       
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                       
   ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["gender": selectedYearPicker])
    
    
}
```

If I make this, there will be a new dataset:

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()
                          
    db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "x")
                   .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                       if err != nil {
                           print("Failed")
                           return
                       }

                       let  userdocid = querySnapshot!.documents[0].documentID
                       db.collection("users").document(userdocid).setData(["koordinaten" : selectedYearPicker])
                       
                       
                       
                      
                    
                   }
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a delegate method to find out when the user has chosen a row (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview). Then, I'm assuming that you want it tied to a user ID of some sort in Firebase, but we don't have any information on how your database is structured. Have you looked at the documentation Firebase provides about writing data?

Comment: Yes i read the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write .  My Database has No Special structure...Users/userID/username. The real struggle is where i have to Push the Data to the Cloud.

Comment: I have Edit my Question.

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted?

Comment: yes. but this is now a firebase question, which I edited.

Comment: it is writing nothing new in the database...weired.